# How to make random data without repetition on ClikListener

Tags: php, android, random

I want to show a random question. On my layout there's an imageView and a button. An imageView will replace with a question which located in my server, and a button for the next question. I made randomize question in my PHP. But every time I clicked next Button, some question showing again, it's because every time I clicked next Button, it will execute the randomize PHP. My question is, how to make next button without execute randomize PHP?

It's my PHP code:

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);

$database_name="db_ipa";
mysql_select_db($database_name);

$arr = array();
$q = mysql_query("select * from biologi order by rand() limit 10");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        $temp = array(
            "no" => $row['no'],
            "soal"=>$row['soal'],
        );
        array_push($arr, $temp);
    }   
$data = json_encode($arr);
$data = str_replace("\\", "", $data);
echo "$data";
?>
```

It's my onClick method:

```
public void next(View v){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    String url ="http://192.168.137.1/server/soal.php";
    String json = jParser.makeHttpRequestPOSTNew(url);
    Log.d("json", json);

    ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json);
        StringBuffer str[] = new StringBuffer[jArray.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){

            if(i==10){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Nilai.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            str[i] = new StringBuffer();

            JSONObject soal = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String sSoal = soal.getString("soal");


            img1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL("http://192.168.137.1/server/" + sSoal).getContent()));

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: The PHP should definitely be returning randomized results, are you sure the getContent line is returning the right stuff? Is that just an image URL or is that running more code server side?

Comment: Check the server logs to check whether the request is making it to the server each time. It's possible that the response is being cached somewhere.